# How to go from a DNS name to a IP:PORT on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, port, dcos

I'm trying to setup multiple different websites on a single cluster of servers (DC/OS). These servers are load balanced via ELB and the websites are spread out across the servers (each website has it's own port that stays the same on all the servers). What I want to do is something like:

```
example.com -> [elb public dns]:8080  
example2.com -> [elb public dns]: 9000
```

I found a way to do this via multiple application ELBs. I can essentially listen on port 80 on multiple different ELBs, each ELB for a specific website. These ELBs are then directed to the proper "target group". However, I'm not sure if this is a good solution since I need to pay for multiple ELBs just for routing my requests from DNS -> IP:PORT. Is there a better way to do this on AWS?

Comment: DNS cannot do this for you, and the way you described is the only way to do it at the moment, if you rely on the ELB to do it -- you need multiple ELBs -- but the ability to route on hostnames with a single Application Load Balancer (ELB 2.0) might be something they introduce in the future. Currently, ALB can only select targets by path pattern (not `Host:` header) but according to the initial announcement, [*"Over time, we plan to give you access to other routing methods"*](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/). Meanwhile, @MichaelHausenblas has the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in DC/OS there is Marathon-LB (MLB) available as a Universe package. MLB is a HAProxy-based load balancer that can be configured exactly in the way you need it, see the section 'Virtual hosts' in the [Marathon-LB docs](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/service-discovery/marathon-lb/usage/).

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering what the performance penalty is to using MLB. I'm thinking about using the ELB solution since it's not going to be taking resources away from the rest of the cluster. I'm not sure how much CPU/MEM will need to be allocated to MLB to make sure it works well.